# how to get specific value from json in node red?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, node-red

```
 var data = {};                                                                                             
 var data_tester;                                                
 data.payload ={
     "age" : "24",                                                         
     "hometown" : "Missoula, MT",                                                         
     "gender" : "male"
 },                                                         
 data_tester = JSON.parse(data.payload);     

 return data_tester.age;
```

This is my program, and I am trying to figure out how to extract value for age, out of this json. I am using ibm bluemix iot watson,
the error I am getting is :

> SyntaxError: undefined:1 [object Object] ^ Unexpected token o

Comment: You have a comma (`,`) after `data.payload`. It should be a semicolon (`;`). Also, you don't need to do `JSON.parse(data.payload)`. That isn't JSON, it's an object. It's already "parsed".

Comment: msg.payload ={
     "age" : "24",                                                 
     "hometown" : "Missoula, MT",                                                         
     "gender" : "male"
 };

 return msg.payload.age;                                
After changing program, I am getting                                            TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_msgid' of 24

Comment: That's a different problem entirely and probably isn't directly related to this code. Try to debug it yourself then if you get stuck, ask another question on here with the exact details of how to recreate it and what you have done to try and solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a message object from a function node. You code returns just the `age` value which is just an *int*.

The error you describe is because Node-RED is trying to add some internal state (`_msgid`) to the output and can not because it's not an object. The correct way to do things is to either return the whole data object e.g.

```
var data = {};
data.payload ={
  "age" : "24",
  "hometown" : "Missoula, MT",
  "gender" : "male"
};
return data;
```

or if you really do just want to return an integer value:

```
var data = {};
data.payload = 24;
return data;
```